# How do I modify existing themes in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, themes, customization

Is there any way to modify the theme that comes with Ubuntu 12.04? It was possible with Ubuntu 10.x.

I wonder why they removed the basic customization. Are there any improvements in this area for 12.04?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way I know of is to install [gnome-tweak-tool](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/introducing-gnome-tweak-tool-gui-to.html) for any adjustments such as cursors, fonts and icon packs. This allows you to adjust these options on-the-fly and works with both Unity and Gnome Shell (although some of the features, like Shell Extensions, expect Gnome Shell to be installed).

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was downvoted. It's a perfectly valid answer to this question. Particularly after the OP provided extra information. +1

Answer (score 7):

Just go to `/usr/share/themes` and you will find the theme files.

For instance if you want to edit the Ambiance theme then get into the Ambiance theme folder and you'll find all the CSS and settings files, its really very basic it all consisits of CSS styles and color codes with some images.

Comment: I did a lot of that (editing CSS by hand) in 11.10 because the convenient interface available in 11.04 vanished in 11.10 and hasn't reappeared in 12.04. _Gnome Tweak Tool_ and the interface provided by _Cog Wheel, System Settings, Appearance_ allow one to choose themes but not to slightly modify them. For that, editing the css files by hand is a must if one wants things _just so_.

Comment: For example, this is how to produce my favorite theme (which I love especially together with a sky-blue desktop background):
`sudo cp -a /usr/share/themes/Ambiance /usr/share/themes/Ambiance-blue` and then
`sudo sed -i 's/#f07746/#3999e7/g' \`find /usr/share/themes/Ambiance-blue -type f | fgrep -v .png | xargs fgrep -l '#f07746'\``

Comment: regarding my previous comment: a "derivative" theme, like the `Ambiance-blue` I gave instructions for, should be kept up to date. E.g., you could check every now and then whether the differences between the original and the derivative theme are limited to the changes you expect. I they are not, it's best to rebuild the derivative theme directory from scratch. BTW, the above `Ambiance-blue` theme is in fact a nice orange and blue theme, where the blue is used for highlighting, progress bars, etc. etc., and nicely complements the orange.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, customization of themes is improved radically in Ubuntu 12.04.

GTK3 themes, which is used by most applications in Ubuntu 12.04, uses the same language that is used to style web pages. You can [read about CSS on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS). This means it has become much easier to learn how to do this since there's thousands of tutorials and books on the subject. Styling GTK2 is not nearly as friendly.

Ubuntu 10.x used a different platform than Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04 uses. So it's not a matter of having removed things. It's mostly a matter of not everything being implemented yet. It's not the same software, so you can't use the same programs to customize them.

Still, there are many customization programs you can download and use. Remember that Ubuntu 12.04 is a Gnome 3 operating system. It's Gnome you want to theme.

Comment: so i have to wait. till they come up with good customization programs.

Comment: There are good customization programs. The question is what it is you want to customize. Since you didn't ask, I couldn't answer. It's probably suited to be a question of its own, but try to be specific.

Comment: actually I wanted to modify font face and size for my current theme.

Comment: In that case, I'll recommend agc93's answer.