# How to get normal Ubuntu orange color in window titlebar using Human-Clearlooks theme?

Tags: 18.04, themes, 18.10, ubuntu-mate, gtk-2

I have Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS installed. Previously I got this problem on MATE 17.10.
I like old-fashioned Human-Clearlooks theme, so I installed `human-theme` package.

But it has strange silver background color in window titlebar:

[image: incorrect silver color in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS MATE]

In 16.04 LTS it has normal Ubuntu orange color - see screenshot for comparison below:
[image: correct orange color in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS MATE]

I have already reported [bug 1721955](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/human-theme/+bug/1721955) to LaunchPad, it confirmed by other user.

How can I debug the issue? Do you have any ideas?

How to get GTK2-based themes working again in GTK3-based Ubuntu?

**Update 20180505**: Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS is affected too. We have a [discussion on ubuntu-mate.community](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/problems-with-gtk2-themes-such-as-human-theme-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-mate-poll/16516).

**Update 20190128**: Ubuntu MATE 18.10 and upcoming 19.04 are affected too.

**Update 20190131**: below are the screenshots from Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS using Human theme -

- Gtk2 demo (named `gtk-demo`)

  > [image: gtk2]
- Gtk3 demo (named `gtk3-widget-factory`)

  > [image: gtk3]

both greys are different here. But on Ubuntu 16.04 MATE LTS the Gtk2 window title is orange.

Comment: Is this at all useful?  https://askubuntu.com/a/126056/225694

Comment: @ElderGeek thanks, but it will not help. Some GTK internals were changed, I do not know how to debug them.

Comment: Suggestion: Install [gtk-3-examples](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gtk-3-examples&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and run `gtk3-widget-factory` and take screenshot of it (does the grey window title still appear). This will clarify that the issue is not exclusive to MATE, but GTK+ 3 in general.

Comment: @clearkimura great suggestion, but Human uses Gtk2, not Gtk3. Added two screenshots based on your suggestion.

Comment: @N0rbert Yes, I am aware that Human uses GTK+2. I wanted to clarify if the same effect is applicable to any GTK+ environment. Btw, I tried Human theme on Xfce; somewhat works but not showing the correct color shade for window title. So the issue is likely exclusive to MATE.

Comment: I did some trials and errors until just now and I think I "partially" solved the issue. I need to redo the steps to be sure. I will write an answer that works for MATE (but not compatible with other DE), if nobody manage to provide the full answer in time.

Comment: @clearkimura nice to hear. Also you may want to read [my analysis on MATE community](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/problems-with-gtk2-themes-such-as-human-theme-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-mate-poll/16516/4?u=norbert_x).

Comment: @N0rbert I am aware of the MATE forum as linked in OP. I think I will focus on Human-Clearlooks that has Ubuntu orange color (#FFBE6B). That will make easier to answer. P.S.: Not an answer for MATE forum, but good enough for AU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Human-Clearlooks** needs GTK+3 support to be useful.

With some efforts, the legacy theme can be adapted and can be used in newer releases of Ubuntu and the derivatives. The title bar with Human theme however, will only be visible when Metacity window manager is used.

> **Useless warning**: Some window managers may not show the title bar with Human theme at all. For GTK+ desktop environment, if the client-side decoration a.k.a. [header bars in GNOME](https://developer.gnome.org/hig/stable/header-bars.html.en) is used by default, user might want to [disable that](https://askubuntu.com/q/961161/37165) and replace with title bar for desired appearance. Hence this useless warning or the warning of becoming useless (pun included).

The following instructions will assume that:

- user has installed the required packages from the Universe repository: [`human-theme`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=human-theme&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and exactly [`mate-themes`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mate-themes&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and prefer to do either;
- **Setup A (easy)**: Human-Clearlooks theme with Blue variant or,
- **Setup B**: Human-Clearlooks theme with Blue/Orange variant.

The required packages would provide the base theme: **TraditionalOk** is recommended. More information is found at lower half of this post, under **Troubleshooting** section.

### Setup A (easy)

MATE, like GNOME2, has a native way to easily customize GTK+ theme. User will choose one of available themes and then customize to mix and match with other themes.

Go to **Control Center > Appearance - Theme** and select the base theme: **TraditionalOk**. Click **Customize...** and change the options in respective tab accordingly.

- Controls: `TraditionalOk`
- Window Border: `Human` (changed from `TraditionalOk`)
- Icons: `Humanity` (changed from `MATE`)
- Pointer: `MATE`

Click **Close** to finish and user will see a new entry *Custom* that will appear as the first entry. The changes are applied immediately, but not persistent. To make the changes persistent, select the customized theme and click **Save As...** and enter **Name** and **Description** as desired or accordingly.

- Name: `TraditionalHuman`
- Description: `TraditionalOk customized with Human window border and Humanity icons` (optional)

Finally click **Save** and user will see the customized theme is now renamed from *Custom* to the name of choice. This will automatically create `~/.themes/TraditionalHuman/index.theme` for the customized theme.

[image: Setup A - Human-Clearlooks with Blue variant]

As a result, we have recreated Human-Clearlooks theme with Blue variant. The Blue colour comes from the base theme: TraditionalOk, a GTK+3 port of Clearlooks from `mate-themes` package.

**Compatibility**: MATE/GNOME2 desktop environment only.

**Limitation**: Setup A does not provide option to freely change the colour. Customization is limited to the number of available themes to mix and match. Whichever themes that were used should not be removed, otherwise the customized theme will be broken.

### Setup B

This setup will use selected parts of available themes to create a new theme: simply named "TraditionalHuman" with minimal dependence on these packages: [`gtk2-engines`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gtk2-engines&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), [`humanity-icon-theme`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=humanity-icon-theme&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and [`dmz-cursor-theme`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=dmz-cursor-theme&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). Take note as follows.

- For Human-Clearlooks with Blue variant (same as **Setup A**), follow only these steps: 1, 2, Final.
- For Human-Clearlooks with Orange variant, follow all steps below.

**Step 1**: Create a local theme directory at `~/.themes` and copy the following selective files from the available themes to the local theme directory. Available themes to use: Human, Human-Clearlooks, TraditionalOk.

```
$ cd $HOME
$ mkdir -p .themes/TraditionalHuman
$ cd .themes/TraditionalHuman
$ cp /usr/share/themes/Human/index.theme .
$ cp /usr/share/themes/Human/cursor.theme .
$ cp -R /usr/share/themes/Human/metacity-1/ .
$ cp -R /usr/share/themes/Human-Clearlooks/gtk-2.0/ .
$ cp -R /usr/share/themes/TraditionalOk/gtk-3.0/ .
```

**Step 2**: Edit `index.theme` file with the following content to define the local theme.

```
$ nano index.theme
[Desktop Entry]
Type=X-GNOME-Metatheme
Name=TraditionalHuman
Comment=Make TraditionalOk more Human
Encoding=UTF-8

[X-GNOME-Metatheme]
GtkTheme=TraditionalHuman
IconTheme=Humanity
MetacityTheme=TraditionalHuman
CursorTheme=TraditionalHuman
```

**Step 3**: Edit the lines containing `theme_selected_bg_color` and `core_color_a` and replace the hexadecimal value to `#ffbe6b`. Precaution: Keep the semicolons `;` at the end!

```
$ nano gtk-3.0/gtk.css
...
@define-color theme_selected_bg_color #ffbe6b;
...
@define-color core_color_a #ffbe6b; /* Core color for blue widgets in TraditionalOk. */
...
```

**Step 4**: Edit the line containing `selected_bg_color` and replace the hexadecimal value to `#ffbe6b`. Precaution: That is a single long line. Keep the `\n` instances!

```
$ nano gtk-3.0/settings.ini
...
gtk-color-scheme = "base_color:#ffffff\nbg_color:#edeceb\nfg_color:#000000\nselected_bg_color:#ffbe6b\nselected_fg_color:#ffffff\ntooltip_bg_color:#f5f5b5\ntooltip_fg_color:#000000\ntext_color:#1a1a1a\nlink_color:#0000ee\nvisited_link_color:#551a8b"
...
```

**Final step**: Change the theme and enjoy.

Go to **Control Center > Appearance - Theme** (or any supported theme manager) and select the created theme "TraditionalHuman". The changes will be applied after several seconds.

[image: Setup B - Human-Clearlooks with Orange variant]

As a result, we have recreated Human-Clearlooks theme with Orange variant. The Orange colour comes from the hexadecimal value `#ffbe6b` that is used in the original Human-Clearlooks theme.

**Variation**: If user wish to have Human theme with both Blue and Orange variants, make sure to *give a different name for each variant*. That means, user should specify the different names for the created theme directory and every instance of the name used in `index.theme` file.

For example, I renamed Blue variant as "TraditionalHuman" and Orange variant as "TraditionalHumanMore" that are shown in the screenshot as follows.

[image: Setup B - Human-Clearlooks with Blue/Orange variant]

User can also create more variations with different colour likewise.

**Compatibility**: MATE/GNOME2 and other GTK+ desktop environment.

**Limitation**: Setup B mostly relies on user initiatives. The theme documentation might be helpful, but rarely found. Customization is either doable or impossible: depends on whether user can understand how the theme files work or otherwise.

### Troubleshooting

Additional notes to understand how theme works as follows.

**The base theme**: This should be the most compatible theme. A common mistake is that user tend to use the legacy theme, which is the least compatible to begin with. Do not use, and I mean *do not use* Human theme as the base theme (repeated on purpose).

Example of a "wrong" base theme that cannot be customized as expected:

[image: Human theme cannot be customized as expected]

**Colour selection**: Check the original theme files to be sure, and *do not* use colour picker against the apparent colour seen on the desktop. The apparent colour is not the actual colour: Human-Clearlooks uses Ubuntu Orange (#ffbe6b) as the main colour, but the title bar with Human theme *does not* show this colour itself.

**Install directory**: The customized theme is installed for current user only at `~/.themes` in the Home directory. For system-wide users, install to `/usr/share/themes` instead. System-wide themes must be installed with proper permission `755`, otherwise the theme may appear broken.

**Yet unusable**: Regardless of setup, use theme files for the same release. *Do not* mix theme files from different releases, otherwise the result is an unusable theme!

I have at least tested TraditionalOk from `mate-themes` package on all supported LTS releases at this time. Theme files for the same release will always work. Exceptional case: theme files in 14.04 and 16.04 are fairly backward and forward compatible, with little to no apparent defects.

```
|      \theme |       TraditionalOk      |
| system\     | 18.04  | 16.04  | 14.04  |
| ----------- | ------ | ------ | ------ |
| 18.04       | OK     | BROKEN | BROKEN |
| 16.04       | BROKEN | OK     | FAIR   |
| 14.04       | BROKEN | FAIR   | OK     |
```

Example of a "broken" appearance (narrow alignment in menu bar), and also an unsupported window manager with Human theme (only had some hint of Ubuntu Orange):

[image: Human-Clearlooks with an incompatible release and environment]

**Other environment**: Human-Clearlooks was designed for GNOME2 and Metacity window manager. Cinnamon with Muffin window manager may support the Human theme natively. Other window manager like Xfwm or Openbox might require additional configuration to show the exact appearance. That will be too broad and will not be covered in this answer.

User can hack any theme files; however, be prepared *to spend at least few hours or may be several days* in test environment. Hacking theme files is usually not worth the time (try again by own... without looking at this answer). Not to mention that [GTK+ theme documentation is rarely found](https://askubuntu.com/q/867050/37165).

The most simple solution: use whatever theme that works for newer releases.

**TL;DR**: Use a theme that supports GTK+3 and customize from that. Unless user has a great interest in themes, not worth looking at theme files with jumbled codes. I had a quick look and thought easy to fix, but instead took several days to reach this answer.

Comment: It's fantastic, actual and comprehensive answer! Thank you very much! I got TraditionalHuman working (followed Setup B).